# Why IntelliJ can't find SBT snapshot dependencies?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0, sbt, playframework-2.3

I have a Play 2.3 Scala project which runs perfectly when started with the **activator run** command. However, if I try to start it in IntelliJ 13 from the **Run/Debug Configurations** option there's a problem with resolving snapshot dependencies.

According to logs following repositories has been checked in order to find dependencies:

```
[warn]  module not found: org.package#my-dep;1.0-SNAPSHOT
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\MyUser\.ivy2\local\org.package\my-dep\1.0-SNAPSHOT\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/package/my-dep/1.0-SNAPSHOT/my-dep-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[warn] ==== Typesafe Releases Repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/org/package/my-dep/1.0-SNAPSHOT/my-dep-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
```

Dependencies are present at my **~/.ivy2/cache** directory. I also have there other dependencies which aren't marked as snapshots and it looks like IntelliJ doesn't have a problem with finding them. It only applies to snapshots.

**Update**

It looks like IDEA ignores my *~/.sbt/repositories* file where snapshot repository is defined and uses default SBT plugin configuration.

Is it actually possible to configure IDEA so it would use my custom repository definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried without success to set custom sbt-launcher in *Settings -> SBT -> Launcher -> Custom*.

[image]

After I run my application with **Run configuration** I could see in the logs that for some reason launcher that I specified was overridden by another which was part of the Scala plugin.

```
-Dsbt.global.base=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\sbt-global-plugin3401565420094215394stub -classpath C:\Users\User\.IntelliJIdea13\config\plugins\Scala\launcher\sbt-launch.jar
```

Finally I managed to force IDEA to use my *~/.sbt/repositories* by adding `-Dsbt.repository.config=C:\Users\User\.sbt\repositories` to the Run Configuration JVM Options.

[image]

I have also set **-Dsbt.override.build.repos=true** to make sure that only repositories listed in my custom configuration are used.